# Set of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is equinumerous to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that the set $\mathcal{C}:=\{f\mid f\in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}\mid f \text{ is continuous}\}$ is equinumerous to $\mathbb{R}$.

To achieve this, I note that an $f\in\mathcal C$ is ''pinned down'' by $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. if I know how $f$ behaves on $\mathbb{Q}$, I know all of $f$, since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is continuous. So there is an easy injection from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\{f\mid f\in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Q}\mid f\text{ is continuous}\}$.

The latter set can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, but I'm afraid that fact won't help me, since (as I believe): not $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}\preccurlyeq\mathbb{R}$.

Could someone *hint* me into the right direction on proving $\mathcal{C}\sim\mathbb{R}$ (via $\mathcal{C}\preccurlyeq\mathbb{R}$)?

Comment: Actually your "easy bijection" is not a bijection, because there are continuous functions $\mathbb Q\to\mathbb R$ that don't extend to any continuous function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, such as $$f(q)=\begin{cases}1 & \text{when }q^2>2 \\ 0 & \text{when }q^2\le 2\end{cases}$$ But it _is_ an injection into $\mathbb R^{\mathbb Q}$, and you can then use Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I will fix this in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $$\vert \mathbb R^{\mathbb N} \vert = \vert (2^{\mathbb N})^{\mathbb N} \vert = \vert 2^{\mathbb N \times \mathbb N} \vert  = \vert 2^{\mathbb N} \vert = \vert \mathbb R \vert$$

Comment: Ah alright, so I was wrong when saying not $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}\sim\mathbb{R}$. Would it however be doable to construct a specific bijection for each of above steps

Comment: @konewka Yes, it is possible to construct a specific bijection (injective functions are easy, and then the constructive proof oc Cantor-Schreder-Berenestein "seals the deal"). And anyways, diving into cardinality arithmetics, the above equalities are easy to prove.

Comment: Indeed, after one minute of trying, I found those bijections aren't hard to find

Comment: @FD_bfa Because as $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, a continuous map from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ is defined by the values it takes on $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: $\lvert \mathcal C \rvert = \lvert \mathbb R^{\mathbb Q} \rvert = \lvert \mathbb R^{\mathbb N} \rvert$.